# Clarification: App color changes for different modal devices but using same color code in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an android apk, but it shows different colors for the screens in different modal phones.

Does it behave like this or how can i know it will shows different color in different modals for the same color code?

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:id="@+id/refresh_layout" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="@color/orange" 
tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can define your own code combinations in colors.xml file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
<color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
<color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
<color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
<color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
<color name="black">#FF000000</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
<color name="grey">#AEAAAA</color>
<color name="background">#D6D5D5</color>
<color name="link_color">#0575CD</color>
</resources>
```

and this wherever you like it won't be changed then I think

Comment: But I have used defined color from my xml. It also shows different color in my UI.

Comment: post your code bro

Comment: can you edit your post and post this whole xml code and colors.xml

Comment: everything looks perfect.did you got any errors in your logcat please check